# Interpreting odds ratios in log linear model output for 3 x 3 table and interaction term

Tags: r, glm

I am having trouble interpreting the odds and odd ratios from a log-linear model of a three by three contingency table.

Reproducible example:

```
colour<-c(rep(c("red","blue","green"),3))
size<-c(rep("High",3),rep("Med",3), rep("Low",3))
Freq<-c(1,145,10,2,30,51,11,62,68)

data<-as.data.frame(cbind(colour, size, as.numeric(Freq)))

mod1<-glm(Freq~colour*size, data = data, family=poisson())
 summary(mod1)
```

What I would like to present are the odds (and 95% Confidence interval) of

- An object being blue, given that it is high
- An object being green, given that it is high
- An object being red, given that it is high

Then the odds ratio such that I can state that the odds of being blue, given the object is high are ?? times higher/lower (plus 95% CI) than being green (given high)

I would like these figures for each combination of colour/size.

I am not sure which model parameters I need to exponentiate to get these odds

I have read this example, which is somewhat similar, but still could get to the answer I needed.

[Generalized Linear Regression Model With Binary Exposure and Interaction Terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575321/generalized-linear-regression-model-with-binary-exposure-and-interaction-terms)

Thanks v. much